# How tall is Galactus?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four, galactus

Galactus is one of the *Fantastic Four* comic series' villains. It is said he can eat planets, so he must be huge. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find it anywhere, but maybe I could have missed some comic where it was stated.

So how tall is Galactus?

Comment: Oooh, about ... *holds hands apart* this tall, I'd say. *moves hands fractionally wider* maybe this tall.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**28 Feet 9 Inches** (9.07 meters)

> **Height**
>
> 28'9" (variable)

Although he can be any size he want, he's usually about that size.

[Source: Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Galactus)

As to how he eats planets, he doesn't use his mouth. Rather, he converts the planet to cosmic energy and absorbs it. See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58804/what-was-galactus-feeding-on-in-planets/58809#58809) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: How does he eat planets if he's only as tall as a telephone pole?

Comment: iirc, he converts them into energy first.

Comment: I feel like a further explanation would be useful.

Comment: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58804/what-was-galactus-feeding-on-in-planets/58809#58809) contains a better description of how he eats planets.